# Julia @code_warntype warning when two different return types are expected

Tags: types, julia

I made a function called `jacobian` that creates 4 sparse matrices with `Float64` entries, make the calculations, and depending on the keyword argument `stacked` being `true` or `false`, returns all four separately,
`return A1, A2, A3, A4`,
or stacked as a single matrix,
`return vcat(hcat(A1,A2), hcat(A3,A4))`.
Running the function with the `@code_warntype` macro gives me the warning:

```
Body::Union{NTuple{4,SparseMatrixCSC{Float64,Int64}}, SparseMatrixCSC{Float64,Int64}}
1 ─ %1 = Main.:(var"#jacobian#29")(false, #self#, Y, V)::Union{NTuple{4,SparseMatrixCSC{Float64,Int64}}, SparseMatrixCSC{Float64,Int64}}
└──      return %1
```

with the `::Union...` parts marked in red, which I don't think is a good sign. Is this considered type instablility? If yes, how can I solve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does indeed mark a type instability, though it will usually be less bad than `Any` being inferred as return type. E.g. the `eigen` function of `LinearAlgebra.jl` will return either a complex or a real matrix based on if the input was Symmetric/Hermitian.

Since the result type in your case only depends on an argument being `true` or `false`, you could wrap it in a `Val` to dispatch between the two variants.

Comment: if there is a `Union` of two concrete types then the Julia compiler is able to handle this, e.g. a very typical case of such unions is a union of some type and `Nothing` or `Missing`. As a general comment I think it would be cleaner to have a first function that returns a `Tuple` and a second helper function that does `hvcat` based on the return value of the first function.